# Passing SUBREPORT_DIR to subreport when the path points inside a JAR file [Jasper Reports 4.5]

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm having problems passing the `SUBREPORT_DIR` path to my subreport. The reports are actually in the same folder, but inside a JAR file. I've tried something like this (might be inaccurate):

```
parameterList = new HashMap<String, Object>();

URL mainReport = this.getClass().getResource("mainReport.jasper");
String mainReportPath = mainReport.getPath();
String subreportDir = mainReportPath.substring(0, mainReportPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

parameterList.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subreportDir);
```

This path points inside the JAR file, but I get `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : ...` upon report generation. How can I make this work?

**EDIT**:

I tried to define my subreport without the `SUBREPORT_DIR`, but no luck:

```
<subreport>
      <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="475" height="17"/>
      <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{current})]]></dataSourceExpression>
      <subreportExpression><![CDATA["mysubreport.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main problem was, that I was using a custom JAR loader, which Jasper didn't know of. The good news is it is also possible to pass a subreport as `java.net.URL` or `java.io.InputStream`:

Java code:

```
InputStream subInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("sub.jasper");
parameterList.put("SUBREPORT_INPUT_STREAM", subInputStream);
```

JRXML:

```
<subreportExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_INPUT_STREAM}]]></subreportExpression>
```

Comment: Once I do this and try compiling the main report it fails to compile the main report stating that it couldnt find the subreport. I am using ireport to compile the main report. How to resolve this compilation error when using the inpustream.\

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to remove `SUBREPORT_DIR` completely. iReport adds it by default as a convenience to keep track of your subreports. But you don't need to keep it.

In your case the reports are in the same directory and in the .jar, so they'll be on the classpath. Change the reference in the .jrxml from `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "mysubreport.jasper"` to simply `"mysubreport.jasper"`. Then delete the parameter from the report and get rid of your code that tries to figure out what directory to use.

Comment: wouldn't that only work if they where in the default package in the jar? Meaning if in his project he has them in test.reports, this would not work. Or would it know just based of where the main report is?

Comment: I will try this, but do I strictly have to reference the `.jrxml`? I always did it the `.jasper` way.

Comment: Its the .jasper that is called on report generation even though the reference is to .jrxml.!

Comment: Yes, my reference to .jrxml was not quite right. I'll update the post.

Comment: @jschoen, I think it will find it based on the location of .jasper rather than its package. But I didn't test that, and I'm not nearly enough of a Java dude to know. I guess Daniel will confirm what works for him.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you should be able to reference the subreport just based on the location of the compiled jasper file inside the jar. For instance if the subreport is in a package named `test.reports` for the `SUBREPORT_DIR` value you should be able to pass in `/test/reports/`.

If that does not work, try moving the compiled reports into the default package and just set `SUBREPORT_DIR` as `/` instead.

Comment: The only way I could achieve what I wanted is by putting the .jasper files in to the default package.

Answer (score 0):

In the "KEY" property of the subreport object within the main file, try assigning the subreport name defined in the subreport file, so the subreport value will be returned to the main report.