# Url of a subreport with jar java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I created a small java application to make invoice, and I used jesperrepport to make the impression, when I execute my application under netbeans the invoice creation is done normally, but when I execute the same application with My file jar I fall in this exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jrexception:error opening input stream from url:C:\Users\adm\Documents\NetBeansProjects\subrep\dist\subrep.jar!\subrep\subRapport.jasper
```

Here is the code of my java class:

```
public class Subrep {

static DefaultTableModel mod;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);

    String title[] = {"nom", "prenom"};
    String data[][] = {{"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"}};
    mod = new DefaultTableModel(data,title);
    JTable tab = new JTable(mod);
    JScrollPane sc=new JScrollPane(tab);
    sc.setBounds(10, 10, 370, 80);
    f.add(sc);

    JButton b = new JButton("imprimer");
    b.setBounds(150, 110, 100, 25);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                //****************************************
                JRTableModelDataSource jrtAL = new JRTableModelDataSource(mod); 
                Map SUB_DATA1 = new HashMap(); 
                SUB_DATA1.put("jrtAL", jrtAL);

                Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                param.put("SUB_DATA1", SUB_DATA1);

                String filename = "Rapport.jasper";
                String subreport = "SubRapport.jasper";
                InputStream jasperReport = null;

                String subR = this.getClass().getResource(subreport).getPath();
                param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", subR);

                Map simpleMasterMap = new HashMap();
                simpleMasterMap.put("rcc", "RC N°: ");

                List simpleMasterList = new ArrayList();
                simpleMasterList.add(simpleMasterMap);
                JRMapCollectionDataSource simpleDS = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(simpleMasterList);
                jasperReport = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, simpleDS);
                JasperViewer.viewReport(print, false);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    f.add(b);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing SUBREPORT\_DIR to subreport when the path points inside a JAR file \[Jasper Reports 4.5\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739547/passing-subreport-dir-to-subreport-when-the-path-points-inside-a-jar-file-jaspe)

Comment: I DO NOT FIND THE SOLUTION HERE : Passing SUBREPORT_DIR to subreport when the path points inside a JAR file [Jasper Reports 4.5]